# SugarCRM - Custom field data is not showing in list view

Tags: sugarcrm

I have done the following tasks in showing a custom field in the list view.

1. Added a new field named custom_description using studio to the leads
2. Added this field to list view layout
3. Added the following code to listviewdefs.php

as show below:

```
  'CUSTOM_DESC_C' => 
  array (
    'type' => 'text',
    'default' => true,
    'studio' => 'visible',
    'label' => 'LBL_CUSTOM_DESC_C',
    'sortable' => false,
    'width' => '10%',
  ),
```

Still the field shows empty in the list view. What more should I do to show this field in the list view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which output do you expact? Where do you fill some Data in this Field? In EditView or should this be a calculated Field which shows some Data out of your Database?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I am filling the field via Edit View.

Comment: Well, this is strange, you also added this Field to your EditView and the same Field to your ListView? You can add these Fields also by using the SugarCRM Studio.

Comment: stupid question maybe but did you perform a repair/rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

You don't require to add code manually into listviewdefs.php file if you've created field from studio & assigned it to list view layout.

Just follow the below steps and check:
1. Add field from studio
2. Assign field to list view layout from studio (make sure you will able to see field on to layout after click on save & continue button)
3. If required, perform repair/rebuild